# ORACLE APEX PL/SQL Function body displays but does no pass back to table

Tags: oracle-apex

Source Used:            Only when current value in session state is Null
Source Type:            PL/SQL Function Body
Maintain session state: Per Session

Source:

```
 DECLARE

   v_user VARCHAR2(20);

 BEGIN

  SELECT   CREATED_BY INTO v_user 
  FROM CA_OFFER_ACTION
  WHERE OFFER_ACTION_ID = :P22_OFFER_ACTION_ID;

  return v_user;

 EXCEPTION 
       when OTHERS THEN
      --    err_code := SQLCODE;
        return :APP_USER;    
 END;
```

So on the page it display's the user but when I submit the page the v_user value is not passed back to update the table

Answer (score 0):

No worries I figured it out. I place the code in the default field and  used `select acf2_lid_id || ' - (' || prfd_na || ')' d, acf2_lid_id r
from is_org_assoc`

Comment: Source and Default are two similar but different things. I hope your page works as expected, because your question wasn't clear.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to verify that P22_OFFER_ACTION_ID has a value in session state, even "[in memory session state](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2016/12/in-memory-session-state-use-case.html)" used during page render.

You could add this and check debug log

```
apex_debug.message(':P22_OFFER_ACTION_ID = '||:P22_OFFER_ACTION_ID);
```

Comment: Scott where would add this as I seem to have some other issues with session state on other items it seems.

Comment: I would add it straight after your BEGIN, then check the debug output, even to see if your process was executed in the first place.